# Pin .data/.attr to particular id and class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pin some data or attr to the editButton class, but only to the element of the given thisId.
It works with only class but when I add thisId as a second parameter it stops working. I also tried to use .find() but it also doesnt work.
What I am doing wrong?

```
<a href="#!" class="editButton" id="{{$comment->h_id}}" onClick="editComment({{$comment->h_id}}, `{{$comment->f_text}}`)">


 <script> 
    function editComment(id, text){

   var thisId = "#" + id;

  $(".editButton", thisId).attr("PinComment", "some new comment");
  alert($(".editButton", thisId).attr("PinComment"));
}
</script>
```

Comment: `onclick="editComment(this, text)"` and in the javascript function you have `var thisId = '#' + obj.id. Although it would be better to use `$.on('click')` and get the text dynamically from the page, e.g. from a textbox

Comment: @fra9001, your comment does not help solve the problem at all. It's best to focus on answering the question first and then talk about best practices later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(".editButton", thisId)` is equivalent to `$(thisId).find(".editButton")`; either of the would work if and only if the elements matching `$(".editButton")` are descendants of the element matching `$(thisId)`.

However, from your code snippet, both `$(".editButton")` and `$(thisId)` are same elements, so your usage of `$(".editButton", thisId)` doesn't work as you expect.

Read [this](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) to understand the API you are using better.

To solve your problem, you could go with this approach:

```
var selector = ".editButton" + thisId;
var element = $(selector);

element.attr("PinComment", "some new comment");
alert(element.attr("PinComment"));
```